# invalid xpath in scrapy (python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

hello i'm trying to build a crawler using scrapy
my crawler code is :

```
import scrapy
from shop.items import ShopItem


class ShopspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'shopspider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.organics.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.organics.com/product-tag/special-offers/']



    def parse(self, response):
      items = ShopItem()
      title = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/h3').extract()
      sale_price = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span[2]/del/span').extract()
      product_original_price = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span[2]/ins/span').extract()
      category = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span[2]/ins/span').extract()

      items['product_name'] = ''.join(title).strip()
      items['product_sale_price'] = ''.join(sale_price).strip()
      items['product_original_price'] = ''.join(product_original_price).strip()
      items['product_category'] = ','.join(map(lambda x: x.strip(), category)).strip()
      yield items
```

but when i run the command :  **scrapy crawl shopspider -o info.csv**
 to see the output i can find just the informations about the first product not all the products in this page.
so i remove the numbers between [ ] in the xpath for exemple the xpath of the title ://*[@id="content"]/div/div/ul/li/a/h3 
but still get the same result.
the result is : `<span class="amount">Â£40.00</span>,<h3>Halo Skincare Organic Gift Set</h3>,"<span class=""amount"">Â£40.00</span>","<span class=""amount"">Â£58.00</span>"` 
kindely help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the indexes on your XPaths, they will find all the items in the page:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/ul/li/a/h3').extract() # Returns 7 items
```

However, you should observe that this will return a **list of strings of the selected html elements**. You should add `/text()` in the XPath if you want the text inside the element. (Which looks like you do)

Also, the reason you only get one return is because you are concatenating all the items into a single string when assigning them to the `item`:

```
items['product_name'] = ''.join(title).strip()
```

*Here `title` is a list of elements and you concatenate them all in a single string. Same logic applies for the other vars*

If that's really what you want you can disregard the following, but I believe a better approach would be to execute a for loop and `yield` them separately?

My suggestion would be:

```
def parse(self, response):
  products = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/ul/li')
  for product in products:
      items = ShopItem()
      items['product_name'] = product.xpath('a/h3/text()').get()
      items['product_sale_price'] = product.xpath('a/span/del/span/text()').get()
      items['product_original_price'] = product.xpath('a/span/ins/span/text()').get()
      items['product_category'] = product.xpath('a/span/ins/span/text()').get()

      yield items
```

**Notice that in your original code your `category` var has the same XPath that your `product_original_price`, I kept the logic in the code, but it's probably a mistake.**

Comment: hello for some reason even when i execute your suggestion code i still get one product : <span class="amount">Â£27.55</span>,"Tiny Troubles Natural Intensive Healing Salve â€“ Nappy Balm, Eczema (3..5 Fl Oz/100 Ml) Free Standard Shipping Worldwide",Â£27.55,Â£27.95

Comment: The code I posted is definetly not beign executed. How are you running your spider? Take a look if actually **saved** the code, if the name of the spider beign executed is correct, or if there are other spiders in your project. You can execute the same lines in the code using `scrapy shell` to check it independently.

Comment: i run my spider using the command **scrapy crawl shopspider -o info.csv** i can also open the file info.csv but i can see just one product; and the name of the spider is correct , and there is no othere spider in my project actually its my first spider

Comment: Did you **saved the code** before executing the spider? I know it seems silly but happens. There can be **only ONE method named `parse`** in the spider file. Another thing you can do is put a `print()` statement inside the `parse` method, so you can see if it's executing or not as you run the spider. I can tell you that the code above is not beign executed because of the `<span>` tags. Again, you can test it in `scrapy shell` and see the result.